# How to deploy a Next.js application on Hostinger Vps server

Tags: next.js, hosting, vps

I'm encountering an issue with my Next.js application. Currently, it's running successfully on the IP address 195.35.23.23:3000. However, when attempting to shift it to my custom domain, I'm facing a "502 Bad Gateway" error.

Despite my efforts to configure the application for the new domain, the error persists. I would appreciate any assistance or guidance on resolving this issue.

Thank you!